# How to populate a list with select option for each list item in android

Tags: android, listview

i have consumed a rest service and getting a response after parsing it i am getting a list of items like this=>

```
[Gayatri Hari Mankar, Prajaval V. Kakade, ram  joshi, Revati R Sharma, Sneha M Verma, Sumeet N Wankar]
```

and i already have a `ListView` with `ArrayAdapter` for sending a list to the service as a request.

Now i want to display the response list in the same list view. Please help.

Comment: And what happened when you tried that?

Comment: I have solved it by taking a new array adapter...Thanks for the reply boss!